# how to make the input value back to the original value when using oninput="validity.valid||(value=' ');" instead of empty input slot

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

The code makes the input slot empty when pressing "-", "+" or any special character in input field.
Example: When i type 123 and "-" in the slot ass soon as I press "-" the input field value becomes empty what I want is the input fields value to be back to 123 instead of empty .

```
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" id="quantity2" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```html
<input type="number" value="1" min="1" id="quantity2" onkeypress="if(!event.key.match(/[0-9.]/)) event.preventDefault()">
```

It allows to enter only numbers from 0 to 9 and `.` (decimal point) character.